# CraftQL - Unable to find tags field in matrix field

Tags: graphql, craftcms

I've got a matrix field with a "Tags" field inside:

[image: MAtrix field definition].

I'm using CraftQL to fetch all fields within this entry and generally it works really well, except for that Tags field.

When I run the below query in the CraftQL console in the admin panel, **theBasicsIndustries** returns an array of tags, as expected.

```
query StoryQuery($slug: String!) {
    entry(siteId: 2, slug: $slug) {
      ... on StoriesStory {
        id
        contentBlock {
          ... on ContentBlockTheBasics {
            __typename
            id
            theBasicsName                

            theBasicsIndustries {
              id
              title
            }
          }       
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Produces:

```
{
  "data": {
    "entry": {
      "id": 26,
      "contentBlock": [
        {
          "__typename": "ContentBlockTheBasics",
          "id": "112",
          "theBasicsName": "Some name",
          "theBasicsIndustries": [
            {
              "id": 108,
              "title": "Hospitality"
            },
            {
              "id": 109,
              "title": "Technology"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However when I run the same exact query through the API, it returns

**Cannot query field "theBasicsIndustries" on type "ContentBlockTheBasics".**

1. Is there a special to query for the tags? I tried running the same query via Postman and the same error shows up.
2. Why does it work in the admin console, and not in the API?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather silly, but the problem was caused by a missing permission in CraftQL settings!

The token I was using didn't have the `Query any tag` access.

[image]